# Get the latest Created file name in directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have folder contains audio and text files

I need to get the last created text file and audio file path without looping on the folder or without using mutable array and order using modified data

any idea

Comment: the performance this folder canhave a lot of files

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions:

1. either you have **no complete information** about the files in the folder beforehand - then you will have to loop through them and check the modified date.
2. or you **do have control** over all the things that go into that folder from the beginning - you could then keep a preference that stores the latest file's URL.

Implementation for looping:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] path];
NSArray *docFileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:documentsDirectory];
NSEnumerator *docEnumerator = [docFileList objectEnumerator];
NSString *docFilePath;
NSDate *lastModifiedDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
NSString *lastModifiedFilePath = @"";

while ((docFilePath = [docEnumerator nextObject])) {
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:docFilePath];
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]  attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:nil];
    NSDate currentModifiedDate = [fileAttributes fileModificationDate];

    if (lastModifiedDate < fileModificationDate) {
        fileModificationDate = lastModifiedDate;
        lastModifiedFilePath = fullPath;
    }
}

return lastModifiedFilePath;
```

Comment: any sample code please, I don't have control on it and I cannot do perefrence , because I have many other folders

Comment: how to separate between txt and audio files am sorry for naive questions

Comment: Just check out the docs for `attributesOfItemAtPath`. In this case, use `[fileAttributes fileType];` or better, just check the last component of the file name with `NSString`'s `pathExtension`. Also please consider up-voting and accepting my answer.

Comment: sorry I didn't get the point, and may another question if the directory I want to search in it is in nsstring , please give me the help in that

Answer (score 0):

Another option for the when you are download the file that time you need to manage the .plist file where auto generated and that last value fetch and justify the latest download file name.

show here the one tutorial for that.
Following code is use for the download the audio file and adding the .plist dynamically created

```
NSString *strAudioURL=@"Your sound ";

    // check first locally exists or not
    NSString *strPathToAudioCache=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                   [(NSArray*)NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],
                                   AudioFolder];

    NSDictionary *dOfAudios=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:strPathToAudioCache];

    if([dOfAudios valueForKey:strAudioURL]) {
        [APP_DEL initAndPlayMovie:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[dOfAudios valueForKey:strAudioURL]] andViewController:self];
    } else {
        NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strAudioURL];
        NSString *strPathToDownload=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[(NSArray*)NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],
                                     [strAudioURL lastPathComponent]];

        if(!self.rqstForAudio || [self.rqstForAudio isFinished]) {
            self.rqstForAudio=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:audioURL];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDelegate:self];
            [self.rqstForAudio setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
            [self.rqstForAudio setCachePolicy:ASIUseDefaultCachePolicy];
            [self.rqstForAudio setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDidFailSelector:@selector(failedToLoad:)];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDidFinishSelector:@selector(finishedLoading:)];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
            [self.rqstForAudio setDownloadDestinationPath:strPathToDownload];
            [self.rqstForAudio startAsynchronous];
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know the file name , I just want to get the lateast modified audio and text file

Comment: hey dude when u download the file that name and value insert into .plist file thus that name entry put into the .plist file and now u can access those .plist data creates the dictionary and that access last name of the file

Comment: so first of the download demo then run the application and show the document directory of a application where the one .plist located and open it and u can get idea about it